# Unwanted Autogenerated Link

Tags: links

I have a website and  a link to websitemagazine.com appears on many "website design" phrases throughout the whole website and I didn't insert the link.[image: example of link on website design text]

It also appears in the page source when viewed on the browser:

[image: page source link found]

And the very curious part is that when I delete the words "website design" from that particular text box the link automatically jumps to the next "website design" words in any textbox within page. How is this possible!? and how can I get rid of it?

I have superpose my own link in some of the text replacing it with a link of my own, however there are elements from visual composer where I cannot add a link to the text line and even when I added it in html it doesn't override the "embedded link" (if you can call it that) as is the case in the first image.

If anyone had the same issue in the past and a solution I will greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

XS

Comment: are there any js scripts on the page that look like they could be the cause?

Comment: No, however I just installed a seo plugin (paid version) and somehow there was an automated back-link rule to set all instances of "website design" to be linked to the mentioned url. I deleted it through the plugin and now it's gone. It was 20 instances linked. Even thou I have resolved the issue my main question remains: How did this happened? and the back-link was created on July this year. So I was linked to that site for quite a while and, on the optimistic view, I was at least relieved that it wasn't a url with a high bad impact on my site. Thanks for taking the time. Plugin: Premium SEO

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by installing a premium SEO plugin that checked all my back-links and picked up the culprit: an automated back-link rule that linked all instances of "website design" to the mentioned URL, thus producing the interesting (or rather normal) effect of one instance been deleted and automatically back-linking to the next one. I used Premium SEO plugin.

However part of the question remains unanswered which is: How this did happen? Since I didn't created such back-link rule and it was created on July this year. No one has or had been granted access to my dashboard.

So if anyone experience similar issues you can always begin by checking any automated back-link rule that may or may not be created by you.

On the bright side I was relieved that the back-link wasn't to a more obscure content website.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to view my query and more to those who offer advise.

Have a great year on 2018!

Regards

XS